# fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'mt.exe'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, manifest

I aware of question [Fatal error cannot run 'mt.exe' at compiling VS 2012 C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079611/fatal-error-cannot-run-mt-exe-at-compiling-vs-2012-c-project) but I am not satisfied with answer out there. I converted my visual studio project from VS2010 to VS2012. But when i compiled my solution, I received "fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'mt.exe'" error. As suggested in mentioned link "Set "**Generate manifest" as No in Linker"** is working but not applicable for me. I need to generate manifest. I search out in google but no other applicable answer found. Please provide any help, link to come out of this issue.

Following links are already tried::

1. [Error spawning 'mt.exe'](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50572/Error-spawning-mt-exe)
2. [Connection refused](http://w3facility.org/question/fatal-error-cannot-run-mt-exe-at-compiling-vs-2012-c-project/)

Comment: It is a messed-up-machine problem.  You must first gather evidence, starting with whether mt.exe is actually present and whether it can actually run.  Get insight by using SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following may help:

Much like errors with fxc.exe, copy mt.exe into the same VS directory install files in which you find fxc.exe, this means there's no external linkage required for these exe's and saves a bit of compile time and as long you're using the same vs install, will work for all projects.

Hope that does it for you.

The answer to this question contains an example:
[Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe)