# Executable file does not start with administrator permissions after changing character set

Tags: visual-studio-2013, unicode, character-encoding, administrator

I have an executable file which used the multibyte character and also needs to start it like an administrator. If I run the file Windows asks me to open it like an administrator.

Now I changed the character set to Unicode and it doesn't worked anymore. I only get an error that mt.exe could not be execute. If I set "Generate Manifest" to no VisualStudio 2013 can compile my file.

My project has to be in unicode and the executable file should be open with administrator permissions.

My project settings looks like
[image: Project settings]

## Update 1:

If I set "Generate Manifest" to Yes I get the following error:
[image: Linker error mt.exe]

My project settings looks like
[image: project settings unicode]

In general I have set "Generate Manifest" to No because my executable application will be compiled.

Comment: What is the EXACT error you are getting? Do you have the same problem if you disable the project's generated manifest and instead link in an external manifest file?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added an update to my post =).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'mt.exe'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725256/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I saw this post too. It didn't helped me. I add 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64' into my PATH environment variables and copied mt.exe into the right folder. I can't believe that this happens although I changed the project properties to unicode ...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, I added mt.exe into the right directory, I did everything I could find to solve this problem. I don't know what I can do right now ...

Comment: file a bug report with Microsoft, disable the manifest generation to get rid of the error, and manually link in an external manifest file (via an `.rc`/`.res` file), like I originally suggested.